# Can ComboBox in AjaxToolkit use lazy loading

Tags: asp.net

Can I make ComboBox from AjaxToolkit make call to server every time new letter is entered and update ComboBox items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the AutoCompleteExtended available in the AjaxControltoolkit ?
[AutoCompleteExtender Demo](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)
The control is similar to a combo box and it offers dynamic filtering of results based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Autocomplete extender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) in AJAX control toolkit.

The suggesions for the text entered in the textbox can be populated by using service method.

Check the properties  ServiceMethod,ServicePath.